# Difference between sum and np.sum for complex numbers numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft, complex-numbers

I am trying to split up the multiplication of a dft matrix in to real and imaginary parts

```
from scipy.linalg import dft
improt numpy as np
# x is always real
x = np.ones(4)
W = dft(4)
Wx = W.dot(x)
Wxme = np.real(W).dot(x) + np.imag(W).dot(x)*1.0j
```

I would like that Wx and Wxme give the same value but they are not at all. I have narrowed down the bug a bit more:

```
In [62]: W[1]
Out[62]: 
array([  1.00000000e+00 +0.00000000e+00j,
         6.12323400e-17 -1.00000000e+00j,
        -1.00000000e+00 -1.22464680e-16j,  -1.83697020e-16 +1.00000000e+00j])

In [63]: np.sum(W[1])
Out[63]: (-2.2204460492503131e-16-1.1102230246251565e-16j)

In [64]: sum(W[1])
Out[64]: (-1.8369701987210297e-16-2.2204460492503131e-16j)
```

Why do `sum` and `np.sum` give different values ?? addition of complex numbers should not be anything but adding the real parts and the imaginary parts seperately right ??

Adding the by hand gives me the result I would expect as opposed to what numy gives me:

```
In [65]: 1.00000000e+00 + 6.12323400e-17 + -1.00000000e+00 + 1.83697020e-16
Out[65]: 1.8369702e-16
```

What am I missing ??

Comment: `1 + -j - 1 + j = 0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Up to rounding error, these results are equal. The results have slightly different rounding error due to factors such as different summation order or different levels of precision used to represent intermediate results.

Comment: Are you saying these two ```Wx = W.dot(x)```
```Wxme = np.real(W).dot(x) + np.imag(W).dot(x)*j.0``` are the same up to a rounding error ? because plots really say other wise like it really feel like either there is a mistake in my maths or there is a significant bug. I cann attach plots if it helps.

Comment: @FranciscoVargas -- Try this one:  `1.83697020e-16 + 1.00000000e+00 + 6.12323400e-17 + -1.00000000e+00` (I simply changed the order of the addition).  The big problem is the `1.0` and `-1.0` ... When you start adding numbers that are ~16 orders of magnitude different, rounding errors can be _reallly_ significant.

Comment: So there is no way I can do my split ? To simplify calculations further on my my project I need a variant of ```Wxme```